# In Magento2 when product is add to cart the total price is added which includes product price and Custom Option price

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

When product is Added to Cart total is show in cart which includes **Product Price** and **Custom Option price**.

My Question is Where exactly the **Product price** and **Custom Option Price** are Added Can Anyone Help me out With file path flow.

Thank in advance

Comment: you found the solution your self, Good i am appreciating you. But if you share that solution, that might be useful to all.

Comment: As @TejabhagavanKollepara said, you could share your solution so others can also benefit from it.